# How to scale a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Say I have a 3D vector `V = <x,y,z>` and I want to obtain another vector as `W=<ax,by,cz>`, I think I should multiply it with a vector or a matrix, so that `M*V = W` how can I calculate `M` for this purpose?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like that:

\begin{matrix}
a & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & b & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & c
\end{matrix}

Comment: Wow. I feel like a noob :) Thanks ! Accepting in 9 mins.

Answer (score 1):

M is the matrix

a 0 0

0 b 0

0 0 c